# Is a square of a prime ideal in a UFD always primary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

More concretely,

> Let $R$ be a UFD and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal ideal of $R$. Does it always hold that $\mathfrak{p}^2$ is a primary ideal?

I know that it always holds if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a principal ideal or a maximal ideal, so one needs only consider rings of Krull dimension $\geqslant 3$.

I proposed this question mainly because I'd like to know how well-behaved a prime ideal of UFD could be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find (counter)examples even in polynomial rings over a field; see [here](https://books.google.ro/books?id=RXHxQzxhcGEC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=p2+is+not+primary+northcott&source=bl&ots=nWgOSFEyg2&sig=l8ey37HTDITH4JKXPOUp5N32CS4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=z7gGVaWuDcnZPeC_gZAB&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: A nice example, thanks a lot.